# How to prevent large popup hint in Messages Panel?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2

In my Delphi IDE (XE2) in the messages panel when hovering over the blank line before the Build Succeeded message, I get a very large popup hint displayed that covers the entire screen in which all my library paths are displayed. This occurs on the Output tab of the Messages pane.

Here is a screen shot of where this is happening:
[image]

It is very annoying.

I have some IDE Experts installed:
GExperts
JCL Options

I have looked through the settings and cannot see anything related to where this would be turned off.

Does this happen with anyone else and is there a way to stop it?

Comment: The way to stop it is to stop hovering over that spot.

Comment: Is there any reason why my question deserves a down vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is the text of what command line would be sent to the command line compiler, being displayed in a hint window.

Before the hint:

[image]

With the hint:

[image]

If you look at the first part of that image, it starts with (on my system)

```
c:\rad studio\5.0\bin\dcc32.exe
```

which is the Delphi command line compiler.

The solution is to not put your mouse on the line right below the target compile line (which is the only place you can see this - by hovering the mouse over the line below 'Target SomethingCompile`entry (in my second screen capture, it's the line below`Target CoreCompile`).

If you don't want to see that hint window, don't hover your mouse over it in the first place. (It's like hint text over a label - if you don't want to see the hint, don't leave your mouse pointer over that label.) It's not like it's a huge area on the screen you have to avoid - it's **just that single line of output** in the window.